# NextJS theme loading error when reloading the website

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm having a problem when I reload my website, it doesn't show the DarkMode icon or it takes a while to appear. I followed the instructions on the web but it seems I'm getting an error and don't know what to do

I want when we reload the page, the theme will load immediately instead of having to take a while for the theme to appear.

layout.tsx

```
import { ThemeContext } from "@/context/ThemeContext/ThemeContext";
import "../styles/globals.css";
import "../styles/theme.css";
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Poppins } from "next/font/google";

const poppins = Poppins({
  weight: ["300", "400", "500", "600", "700", "800"],
  subsets: ["latin"],
});

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={poppins.className}>
        <ThemeContext>{children}</ThemeContext>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

ThemeContext

```
"use client";
import { ThemeProvider as NextThemesProvider } from "next-themes";

export function ThemeContext({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <NextThemesProvider attribute="class" defaultTheme="dark">
      {children}
    </NextThemesProvider>
  );
}
```

DarkModToggle

```
"use client";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useTheme } from "next-themes";

const DarkModeToggle: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);
  const { theme, setTheme } = useTheme();

  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true);
  }, []);

  if (!mounted) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <div
      className={`w-16 h-8 flex items-center justify-between p-1 cursor-pointer gap-1 border rounded-3xl`}
      onClick={() => setTheme(theme === "light" ? "dark" : "light")}
    >
      <div className="text-xl"></div>
      <div className="text-xl"></div>
      <div
        className={`w-6 h-6 bg-gray-400 rounded-full absolute ${
          theme === "light"
            ? "transform translate-x-8"
            : "transform translate-x-0"
        }`}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DarkModeToggle;
```

Here I am using tailwindcss library